# Why are there different urls.py in Django 1.8 vs 1.7?

Tags: python, django

In Django 1.8, `urls.py` is written in this way:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

In Django 1.7, `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', views.article_detail),
)
```

Can someone explain why there is a difference - especially in brackets and parentheses (`[` and `(`) and the `patterns()` function?  What is the theoretical background, and how it manifest practically?

Comment: Where you did see the change? In doc? `[0-9]` only matches 0-9 digits only but `\d` would also match Unicode digit chars.

Comment: word patterns is from django 1.7 documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the [1.8 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns):

> patterns() serves little purpose and is a burden when teaching new
>   users (answering the newbie’s question “why do I need this empty
>   string as the first argument to patterns()?”). For these reasons, we
>   are deprecating it. Updating your code is as simple as ensuring that
>   urlpatterns is a list of django.conf.urls.url() instances

Answer (score 4):

In 1.7, you could use a string defining the import path of a view, instead of an actual view function. The first argument to patterns was a prefix that would be used for each following view. This reduced repetition when including multiple views from the same module, i.e.:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', 'special_case_2003'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'year_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'month_archive'),
    url(r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'article_detail'),
)
```

However, this is import "magic" for no good reason. It can hide import errors and overall makes it more difficult to debug incorrect url patterns. For this reason, using strings instead of view functions is deprecated in 1.8, and will be removed in 1.10.

Because `patterns()` serves no other purpose than to add the prefix to the string-based view imports, this too has been deprecated and will be removed in 1.10.